# oftenly why i need to do power cycle/ rebooting router

Tags: networking, router

Scenario: have 80 nodes and 6 switches 1 router (RV082) 
ISP_flows to router
Router_flows to switches(unmanaged 24)
Switches_flows to Nodes

oftenly why i need to do power cycle/ rebooting router 
As we have 5 to 6 host that work on captcha able to work only for a week,after a week, they face exceptions in captcha as they says internet is not working fine for them, when tried to troubleshoot am unable to find anything.like (ping to gateway is fine ping to website that work on captcha fine too)
as soon i restart router or power cycle devices they are able to work fine.
i would like to have help form experts here why am facing this issue's.
what steps i need to be taken for this issue.

kindly suggest me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, and you may have already seen it, but maybe it will help.  Cisco was evidently having this problem with that type of router.  You should check to see if your specs line up with what the poster says.  Long and short: v1 firmware/hardware works great, v2 is buggy, v3 is better but not perfect.

[Cisco Support Forum Post](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11650696/rv082-fails-respond-until-manual-restart)